# textarea resize is not working in IE, I want resize-y in IE and it is working in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I am developing an angular 4 project in that I have to create resizeable textarea only vertical in IE, It is working in chrome and another browser.

I have found some Jquery plugin for resizing in IE but it is not supporting for only vertical and I have multiple textarea in the same page.

[This is a working example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yxpZNv)

CSS

```
.resizable {
   resize: vertical;
  min-height:150px;
}
```

HTML:

```
  <textarea class="resizable">
This paragraph is resizable in all directions, because
the CSS `resize` property is set to `both` on this element.
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use resize in IE

https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-resize

You can use jQueryUI Resizable for textareas.

Include jQuery UI library in your project

then in your jquery code call the line below

$("#textareaId").resizable({ });

Comment: I am using this and it is not working good with angular 4, looking for Pure Javascript solution

Comment: Check this guide and make it work with mouse position

https://stephanwagner.me/auto-resizing-textarea-with-vanilla-javascript